# How to call JQuery function when blur or press enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to release the textfield when I press enter or blur()

Actually I'm ok when blur(), but I need those both things.

This is what I have:

*** JQuery ***

```
$(document).ready(theMain);
      function theMain(){

        $("td").blur(ActTable);

        function ActTable(){
          alert("it works!");
        }

    }
```

*** HTML ***

```
<table>
  <tr><td>myID</td><td>column1</td><td>column2</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode==13) ActTable();">text to change</td>
    <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode==13) ActTable();">text to change</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In fact, this HTML part calls the function but I need to release the textfield instead of type down space. Same as blur() does.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks.

**Edit:** 
I need to release the text field when I press enter, i don't know if i'm speaking correctly but I need the same blur effect when I press enter on that textfield. English is not my native language so, sorry if i'm not speaking well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this gets the job done as you need.

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //wire up blur events
    $('#myTable').on('blur','[contenteditable=true]',function(){
        alert('works');
    });

    //wire up keyup events
    $('#myTable').on('keyup','[contenteditable=true]',function(){
        if(event.keyCode==13){
            $(this).blur();
        }
    });
});
```

The only change needed on the HTML is on the table tag
HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
```

Needed for the Jquery to select the tds necessary in the table. Also remove the onkeyup attribute on the td tags

Have a look and tinker with it here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3599L1b/15/)

Comment: nice job but I need to release the textfield instead of type down space. Same as blur() does.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean a bit. I am not fully understanding what you mean by that

Comment: If you check your example, you will see that when you type something and then you press "enter", the function is being called correctly but "the text field is not released, the effect is not the same than blur effect".

Comment: We almost done, I'm trying to simulate backspace before of the blur effect,  but it doesn't work for me, you know how to do that? I'm trying with             $(':focus').trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 8});

Comment: That is actually separate from the question. But why trigger a backspace? is it for enter so that newline isn't created?

Comment: I don't want that new line of the enter key, that's the reason.

Comment: To remove the newline you also need to remove any alerts. I've updated the fiddle to reflect the change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95642/discussion-between-b-days-and-roberto-sepulveda-bravo).

Answer (score 2):

you need to use  `e.which == 13`

```
if(e.which == 13) {
    alert('You pressed enter!');
}
```

your code

```
$(document).ready(theMain);

function theMain() {
    $("td").on('blur', ActTable).on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            ActTable();
        }
    });

    function ActTable() {
        alert("it works!");
    }
}
```

Comment: As `ActTable()` is called from HTML, It need to be _global_, move the function outside of `theMain` or suggest to remove _inline_ handlers and use jQuery for event handling.

Comment: I need to release the text field when I press enter, I need the same blur effect when I press enter on that textfield. Your code is calling the function well, but the pointer is still inside the TextField. English is not my native language so, sorry if i'm not speaking well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .keyup() method, and check if event.which equal to 13.
So, you could write:

```
$("#yourIdHere").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        //use blur on input
        $("#yourIdHere").blur();
    }
});
```

**Edit**

You could call the blur function after checking the event.which value.

Comment: The pointer is still inside the TextField and I dont want that.